# "Connection closed before recieving a handshake response" When trying to connect Angular with Spring using websockets

Tags: angular, spring, docker, websocket

I'm trying to connect a Angular app with a Spring app using Websockets. When trying to connect throught the Angular app I get the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws:localhost:8071/websocket' 
failed: Connection closed before recieving a handshake response
```

**note:** I use Docker..

I can't seem to find what the problem is. I tested the following things:

- Tested if the Angular app can connect with a websocket server (used: https://www.websocket.org/echo.html) This worked
- Tested if the Angular app can connect with RabbitMQ. (used STOMP 1.1 protocol) This worked.
- Tested if the Spring app can connect with RabbitMQ. (used STOMP 1.2 protocol) This worked.
- Tested if the Spring app can connect with a custom made HTML page. This worked.
- Tested if the Angular app can connect with the Spring app. This did not work.

I thought it is maybe caused by the different STOMP protocols, or maybe I did something wrong in the docker file. If code is needed let me know, I'll provide.

**Docker-compose** (relevant part)

```
version: '3'

services:

frontend:
  build: ./smilei-frontend
  ports:
  - 8070:80

websocket-server:
build: ./smilei_gateway/websocket-server
ports:
    - 8071:8071
image: websocket
depends_on:
  - eureka
  - rabbitmq
environment:
  - EUREKA_URI=http://eureka:8761/eureka
  - BROKER_RELAY_HOST=rabbitmq
```

**Angular app**

```
connect() {
    // connect to stomp where stomp endpoint is exposed
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8071');
    this.ws = Stomp.over(socket);
    const that = this;
    this.ws.connect({}, function(frame) {
        that.ws.subscribe('/errors', function(message) {
            alert('Error ' + message.body);
        });
        that.ws.subscribe('/user/topic/greetings', function(message) {
            console.log("HALLO " + message)
            //that.showGreeting(message.body);
        });
        that.disabled = true;
    }, function(error) {
        alert('STOMP error ' + error);
    });
}

disconnect() {
    if (this.ws != null) {
        this.ws.ws.close();
    }
    this.setConnected(false);
    console.log('Disconnected');
}
```

**Spring app**

```
@Controller
public class WebsocketController {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebsocketController.class);
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;
private final GreetingService greetingService;

@Value("${server.port}")
private String port;

@Autowired
public WebsocketController(SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate, GreetingService greetingService) {
    this.simpMessagingTemplate = simpMessagingTemplate;
    this.greetingService = greetingService;
}

@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendToUser("/topic/greetings") // use @SendToUser instead of @SendTo
public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message, Principal principal) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Received greeting message {} from {}", message, principal.getName());
    greetingService.addUserName(principal.getName()); // store UUID
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
    return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the anwser, I got 2 problems, the first one was that when trying to connect to the Spring application, the server would forward it somehow to the RabbitMQ service. This way it looked like I could only connect to rabbitMQ.